# Get the parameteres of a url

Tags: php

i wanna try to get the parameters of a link when it's **: separated** like below :

`http://localhost/index/test:1`

How can i get test and its value (1) by php?

Thanks in advance ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like genesis said, it is highly recommended that you change the style of the query. The `?param1=value1&param2=param2` format is industry and technology standard.

If you cannot change the query style, instead you can manually parse the request URI.
You can obtain it via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and do some parsing using the [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php), such as [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

This should be a last resort, however.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a rewrite with htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `$_GET` and `.htaccess` as the others have suggested use this.

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost/index/test:1";
$pa = parse_url($url);
$arr = explode("/", $pa['path']);
array_shift($arr);  array_shift($arr);
$arr = explode(":", $arr[0]);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Outputs //

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => 1
)
```

The elements are now stored in an array.

Answer (score -1):

If by `:`-separated parameter you meant `port` number, you can use `parse_url`:

```
parse_url("http://localhost:1000/index/test", PHP_URL_PORT);
```

Although the port number should be right after host address.
If you want to pass some parameters to a url you should use `&`-separated statements (just like everybody else said):

```
?param1=value1&param2=param2
```

If you insist on navigating to this unusual url and want to fetch that `1`, you could get the entire url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.